# Apriori Labels rejected despite other function factors writing rules in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I have a large data set (3.5 million observations and 185 variables) that I'm doing market basket analysis on using `apriori()`, most of the columns have a yes/no result. I've converted my data frame correctly but for some of the yes/no columns one of the factors (usually a yes) will occasionally not run and give an `Error in asMethod(object) : variable is an unknown item label` as the output or it won't write any rules while the others run fine. Since my file is so large I need to narrow down the rules I run via a `lhs =` specification, hence my concern about the sporadic code.

I've checked that the label exists in my dataframe, it does, and I went so far to factor it again just in case that's the issue. When I run `labels()` on my transaction data I can't find any entries with the problematic label despite `table()` showing that some exist. However, I don't have an efficient way to search all the transaction data so I only searched a few hundred transactions so they could still be there.

my csv is a dataframe that has a row per transaction and column for basket items. Its not as wide as it could be because the Yes/no values are in the same column. I've also attached the column name to the cells with a . to make the rules easier to read.  `df2` is the same as ExportMD1.csv

Here's my data conversion

```
tr <- read.transactions('ExportMD1.csv', format = 'basket', sep = ',', cols = 185, header = TRUE)
```

I'll use  `isTreasuryBill` as an example, the table shows that there are 'yes' values

```
table(df2$isInterestBearing)
```

isInterestBearing.n  69745

isInterestBearing.y  276824

I get one of two outputs when I run the following code:

```
rules <- apriori(tr, paramete = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.8, minlen = 2), appearance = list(lhs= "isInterestBearing"))
```

Option 1

```
Error in asMethod(object) : isInterestBearing is an unknown item label
4. stop(paste(indicator[!indicator %in% from$labels], "is an unknown item label", collapse = ", "))
3. asMethod(object)
2. as(c(appearance, list(labels = itemLabels(data))), "APappearance")
1. apriori(tr, paramete = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.8, minlen = 2), appearance = list(lhs = "isInterestBearing"))
```

Option 2

```
Parameter specification:

Algorithmic control:

Absolute minimum support count: 173284 

set item appearances ...[1 item(s)] done [0.04s].
set transactions ...[430165 item(s), 346569 transaction(s)] done [24.73s].
sorting and recoding items ... [177 item(s)] done [0.97s].
creating transaction tree ... done [1.35s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.02s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.04s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.22s].
```

There's no difference in the dataframe or `read.transaction` when these issues occur.

Ideally `apriori()` would run consistently without any errors. I suspect that the reason I'm not getting any rules for some is because the counts are so low but I have no idea why the labels aren't being reliably recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just not using the right item label in appearance. Check what item labels you have in your transactions with

```
itemlabels(tr)
```

The correct item label will be something like `isInterestBearing=y`.

Comment: the item label should be right since ```isInterestBearing.n``` works just fine.

Comment: did you run `itemlabels(tr)`? It is hard to know what is going on without the data and an example that I can run.